# How to force a slider to have a min different of zero in flutter

Tags: flutter, slider

I tried to create  a slider with min value = 10; et max 100;

If min value is different of zero I have issue : value >=min && value <= max is not true.

I have add my slider_value=10.0 in the initstate. but I have always this error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it fails, but exactly the same thing happened to me, and to solve it I changed the `min` and `max` values from `int` to `decimal`, that is, just add `.0`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not actually setting the slider's value. Could you include your code?

If you do this it should work:

```
Slider({
  value: 10.0,
  min: 10.0,
  max: 100.0,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that default Slider value which you set larger than min value and smaller than max

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's no correct answer,
If you're looking for a perfect answer
[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuw818gAlF8&t=666s) will do (Watch from 9:30)